# echo problem in audio/video chat application

Tags: video, audio, echo

I am making an audio/video chat application, i am using Flex, Flash Media Server 3.5, Flash Player 10, and I am facing the problem of echo very frequently. I am using a headset for audio recording.

Answer (score 2):

[Acoustic Echo Cancellation (AEC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_cancellation#Acoustic_Echo_Cancellation) is a particularly tricky problem in telephony, audio/video-conferencing, etc. Even if you're using a headset at your end you can still get echo via the remote end. You need an AEC module in your application otherwise you will need to ensure that both ends always use headsets. Unfortunately AEC is quite hard to implement - you can do something crude with an adaptive [LMS filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMS_filter) but really good AEC tends to only be available as a licensable commercial solution.

Comment: Thanx for the reply ,But i am using headphone at both side.But echo arrives.

Comment: @bindu: OK, in that case it's probably a bug in your code. You'll need to try and isolate where the "echo" is coming from. Try just running the link in one direction and see if you still get the echo. It may be that you are getting some kind of buffer overrun or dropped packets, or perhaps have some kind of logic error in the code which is causing received audio buffers to be played more than once.

Comment: hi 
thanx
i am using these setting

microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
    microphone.setLoopBack(true);
    microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
                microphone.rate = 11
                microphone.gain = 65; 
                microphone.setSilenceLevel( 5, 1000 );
    microphone.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);



//And also set buffertime to 0 
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.bufferTime=0;